# Automatically detect if an antivirus is installed from batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there any way to check if any antivirus software is installed and then uninstall it to replace it with one installed via the batch file?

I doubt there is but I can't find any info on this (I know that I could check if programs are installed but I was wondering if there was a better way).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just curious: What would you use it for?

I understand your question like this: Are there signs that an installed software is an antivirus and that I can search for (basically)?

What you already said is checking for installed programms in general. Combine that with a text document including the more popular antivirus software and search for those with a loop. If you would choose that way you have to be accurate with wat you place in the textfile though.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 that was what I was expecting to be the answer, I was just wondering if there was an easier way. The point of this is that we get a lot of machines in with expired version of McAfee (preinstalled trial) and when installing a service pack it would be nice to throw up an error during the install pack rather than later when you have two antiviruses fighting it out in your registry (it gets quite messy, random errors everywhere).

Comment: So you want to check if the computer has this old McAfee and if so you want to first uninstall it / abort the started installation and then run an independent installer for your new one? That should be possible (eventhough I do not know how, but I am confident others do).

Comment: @geisterfurz007 that is exactly it, and I am in precisely the same situation as you. I've done some basic scripting with batch but that is it.

Comment: Just to make sure: As you marked my answer as solution, I assume it is working properly. Can you confirm that so I can take out the not tested warnings? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researching about a few things needed to perform that, I came up with this:

IT IS NOT TESTED!

```
@echo off
wmic product get name,version | findstr "McAfee">temp1.txt
set /p line=<temp1.txt
del temp1.txt
if "x%line%"=="x" (
   REM string is empty -> file is empty -> prgramm does not exist
   echo "No old McAfee installed"
   pause
   Goto :eof
) else (
   choice /m "Uninstall old one?"
   if %errorlevel%==1(
   REM PLACE HERE
   REM run installer
) else Goto :eof

)
pause
```

Where it says `REM PLACE HERE` you have to do the following (only once to finish the batch file):
Go to the registy editor (regedit) and work yourself through to the keys

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

for a 32-bit software or

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

for a 64-bit software.

now go through the keys and look for the DisplayName key. Work yourself through that until you find the right one. Then look under `UninstallString`.
Copy that and place it instead of the commented line.

Again: This is not tested and I would like another more experienced user to confirm / test on a testmachine.

Answer (score 2):

You can start by this batch file to get some information about your OS and your antivirus installed :

```
@echo off
Title General information about OS and Antivirus by Hackoo 2016
Mode con cols=50 lines=3
cls & color 0A & echo.
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Automatically check & get admin rights
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Set "TmpLogFile=%Tmp%\TmpLogkey.txt"
set "LogFile=%userprofile%\Desktop\%~n0_LogFile.txt"
If Exist %TmpLogFile% Del %TmpLogFile%
If Exist %LogFile% Del %LogFile%
REM  --> Check for permissions
Reg query "HKU\S-1-5-19\Environment" >%TmpLogFile% 2>&1
REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
Echo.
ECHO                        **************************************
ECHO                         Running Admin shell... Please wait...
ECHO                        **************************************

    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c ""%~s0"" %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::          START         ::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Echo.
Echo               Please wait a while .....
If Exist "%LogFile%" Del "%LogFile%"
(
    Echo  **************************** General info ****************************
    Echo Running under: %username% on profile: %userprofile%
    Echo Computer name: %computername%
    Echo Operating System:
    wmic os get caption | findstr /v /r /c:"^$" /c:"^Caption"
    Echo Boot Mode:
    wmic COMPUTERSYSTEM GET BootupState | find "boot"
    Echo Antivirus software installed:
    wmic /Node:localhost /Namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 Path AntiVirusProduct Get displayName | findstr /v /r /c:"^$" /c:"displayName"
    Echo Executed on: %date% @ %time%
    Echo  **************************** General info ****************************
)>"%LogFile%"

Start "" "%LogFile%"
```

Comment: Taking from this you can just extract `wmic /Node:localhost /Namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 Path AntiVirusProduct Get displayName | findstr /v /r /c:"^$" /c:"displayName"`

Answer (score -2):

Might Be Able To Check For Their Directories Like So:

```
if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Avast" (
echo Avast Is Installed!
)else echo Avast Not Installed
```

i dont know where Avast install's itself but this is my best guess